# unable to retrive + characters using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Hello friends facing a problem with AJAX and PHP ???
Let me tell you what i did ...!
I created 2 pages 
 one page (AJAX_view.php) with a drop down with all the blood group in short code like (b+, b-) and i placed my ajax code on the same page. to asynchronously search for the blood groups available in database (MySql).
Now the another page (search.php) has all the php code and the query to retrieve the data from database..
Now the real problem is from the 1st page i passed the string in url to the another page using the code

```
           xmlhttp.open("POST","search.php?q="+str,true);
           xmlhttp.send();
```

and the str here is 'B+' without quotes 
and it doesnt reads the "+" , what it reads is only B... this only happens in the case of "+ " while if i pass the string str as "A-" its give the result without any problem or error and returns result from database
but there are certain blood group like B+ ,AB+ , O+ and there is no result show for them.

```
       $q=$_GET['q'];
```

this is how i retrieve the string on search page..

```
      $select_query="SELECT * FROM blood_donate WHERE blood_group='$q'";
        $res=mysql_query($select_query);
```

this is how i select data from database??
please help

Comment: why are you POSTing values through the querystring? You're mixing GET and POST...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **encode `+`**, otherwise it'll be treated as space (). Use **`encodeURIComponent`** on `str` for this.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","search.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(str),true);
```

if str is `A+` without `encodeURIComponent` it'd generate url `search.php?q=A+`. This makes `$_GET['q']='A '` at the PHP end. (note the space)

With `encodeURIComponent` it'd be `search.php?q=A%2B` which yields `$_GET['q']='A+'`.